# Posix Extended Regex match with find Bash Linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to use find in linux (will be part of bash shellscript) to return a list of files that match a specific type.

Example directory contents:

```
example_bob_log_2014-12-31-23.59.59.dat  
example_bob_log_2017-12-31-23.59.59.dat  
example_llama_log_2017-12-31-23.59.59.dat    
example_carrier_adjst_2017-12-31-23.59.59.dat
example_soup_log_2016-12-31-23.59.59.dat   
example_scenery_adjst_2016-12-31-23.59.59.dat
```

Desired return:

```
example_bob_log_2014-12-31-23.59.59.dat  
example_bob_log_2017-12-31-23.59.59.dat
```

Attempt:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '^(example_bob_log)_[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.dat'
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '^(example_bob_log)_[[:digit:]]{4}\-[[:digit:]]{2}\-[[:digit]]{2}\-[[:digit:]]{2}\.[[:digit:]]{2}\.[[:digit:]]{2}\.dat'
```

Comment: You need to match full path, use `'.*/example_bob_log_[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.dat'`

Comment: Need more details otherwise `find . -name 'example_bob_log_*'` will also work.

Comment: Or `find . -name 'example_bob_log_*.dat'`